# With Xpath, how can I extract 1 image from srcset?

Tags: html, css, xpath

This is the source code:

```
<img alt="" class="xyz" srcset="image1.jpg 500w, image2.jpg 300w, image3jpg 100w" sizes="xyz">
```

Now, I want to extract say, image2.jpg. How do I go about it?

E.g.  I can reach up to srcset. But not beyond

```
//img[@class='srcset']
```

Please help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that tool/library that you use supports that `XPath` syntax, but you can try below expression to get `"image2.jpg 300w"`:

```
tokenize(//img/@srcset, '[*,]+ ')[2]
```

to get just `"image2.jpg"`:

```
tokenize(//img/@srcset, ' [0-9][+\w,]+')[2]
```